# How to mount Glyphicon fonts from WebJars in Wicket

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, wicket, glyphicons, webjars

Using `wicket-bootstrap-core` and `wicket-bootstrap-less` (both version 0.10.5), I have successfully integrated Bootstrap into my Wicket 7 project. The set up is performed in the method

```
private void initBootstrap() {
  WicketWebjars.install(this);

  BootstrapSettings settings = new BootstrapSettings();
  settings.setThemeProvider(new SingleThemeProvider(new MyTheme()));

  Bootstrap.install(this, settings);
  BootstrapLess.install(this);
}
```

The theme class `MyTheme` refers to the LESS file `theme.less`. In this file (which compiles successfully), Bootstrap and the Glyphicons are imported using the directives

```
@import "webjars!bootstrap/current/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "webjars!bootstrap/current/less/glyphicons.less";
```

The only problem is that when I use any of the Glyphicons in my markup, this causes requests for the font files to be downloaded at path `http://localhost:8080/myproject/wicket/resource/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` (same with other extensions). Since no resource is mounted using a class named `fonts`, this results in

```
21:36:35.298 [tomcat-http--31] WARN  o.a.w.c.u.l.WicketObjects - Could not resolve class [fonts]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fonts
        [stack trace omitted]
```

The question therefore is: How do I get these resources correctly mounted? From [this](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Wicket-bootstrap-Bootstrap-3-support-tp4661497p4663918.html) I get the impression that the mounting should be automatic, and from [this](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Resolution-of-url-in-ContextRelativeResourceReference-tp4672147p4672291.html) I furthermore get the impression that this should be a no-brainer.

Comment: By the way, `wicket-webjars` is version 0.5.3 (it's a dependency of `wicket-bootstrap-core` and `wicket-bootstrap-less`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further thinking, I came up with the following solution: Add the line

```
@icon-font-path: '../de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.request.resource.IWebjarsResourceReference/webjars/bootstrap/current/fonts/';
```

to `theme.less` such that the icon URLs point to a location where the files are already mounted.

While this solution actually works, I really hope that there is a less hideous way.

Comment: I had recently a similar problem. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45235995/1988304)