# Wicket with Bootstrap / How to use a font that's provided via webjar?

Tags: css, wicket, font-face, webjars

In my Wicket (with Bootstrap) application, I have the artifact `org.webjars:font-awesome:4.6.3` as a transitive dependency.

[image]

I want to use this font in for styling my page via the CSS file which is associated to the Page `MyBasePage`.

This is an excerpt from `HomePage.css`:

```css
.banned div::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome, serif;
    content: '\f05e ';
    color: #c00000;
}
```

**What is the correct way to make the font accessible for client ?**

The CSS-file `HomePage.css` is properly embedded via
`PackageResourceReference cssFile = new PackageResourceReference
                (HomePage.class, "HomePage.css");`

## Update

Based on the hint of @martin-g , I made these changes to my code

In the application

```java
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication
{
    @Override
    protected void init()
    {
        mountResource("css/font-awesome.css", FontAwesomeCssReference.instance());
    }
}
```

In the page

```java
public abstract class HomePage extends WebPage
{
    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)
    {
        super.renderHead(response);
        CssHeaderItem fontAwesom = CssHeaderItem.forUrl("css/font-awesome.css");
        response.render(fontAwesom);

        PackageResourceReference cssFile = new PackageResourceReference
                (HomePage.class, "HomePage.css");
        CssHeaderItem cssItem = CssHeaderItem.forReference(cssFile);
        response.render(cssItem);
    }
}
```

In HTML (browser) now there are valid links

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resource/com.package.HomePage/HomePage-ver-1500642636000.css" />
```

But in `font-awesome.css` , these links can't get resolved, I guess:

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') ...
```

[image]

Comment: I've created an MCVE based an Wicket quickstart (https://gitlab.com/UlrichK/FontAwesomeWebjar.git) . Execute via Test --> Start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to mount the FontAwesomeCssResourceReference to some "nice url", e.g. in YourApplication#init():

```
mountResource("css/font-awesome.css", FontAwesomeCssReference.instance());
```

This way it will be available at `/context-path/css/font-awesome.css`.

Update: **Ignore the above!**

Here is the change that makes it working:

In HomePage.java

```java
import de.agilecoders.wicket.extensions.markup.html.bootstrap.icon.FontAwesomeCssReference;
public class HomePage extends WebPage
{
    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);
        // add all the components here
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);

    // +++++ the relevant part:
        response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(FontAwesomeCssReference.instance()));
    // +++++

        PackageResourceReference cssFile = new PackageResourceReference
                (HomePage.class, "HomePage.css");
        CssHeaderItem cssItem = CssHeaderItem.forReference(cssFile);
        response.render(cssItem);
    }
}
```

That is, all you need to do is to make sure that font-awesome.css is contributed before HomePage.css.
**The custom code in WicketApplication.java can be removed!**

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what are the advantages of webjars. I do it manually like this and it works well:

[image]

and then in my main page:

```
   @Override
   public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
      super.renderHead(response);
      response.render(BootstrapResources.getFontAwesome());
   }
```

Comment: I'm working with Wicket-Bootstrap. Several fonts and CSS are included there (in webjars). So the question is: how to use these already provided resources **(especially the font)** instead of adding them again manually